# Albums in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create an image gallery in rails.  I have produced a setup that allows you to create an album and upload photos to it.  However, I am stumped on how I could allow the user to set one of the existing images as the album cover in the image's index view.
Anyone have some ideas?  I found that if I used radio buttons, I couldn't figure hout how to determine which image was selected by ajax.  I also don't know how I would force only one image being set as album cover.

Here is my setup:

**Controller**

```
class Admin::AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  def index
    @albums = Album.all
  end
  def new
    @album = Album.new
  end
  def create
    @album = Album.new(params[:album])
    if @album.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created album!"
        redirect_to [:admin, :albums]
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
  def edit
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end
  def show
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
    if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
      respond_with @album
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Album"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    @album.destroy
    @id = @album.id
    FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/image/picture/#{@id}", :force => true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
    redirect_to admin_albums_path
  end
  def random_image
    @image_files = %w( .jpg .gif .png )
    @files ||= Dir.entries(
      "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/uploads").delete_if { |x|
        !@image_files.index(x[-4,4])
      }

    file = @files[rand(@files.length)];
    @files.delete file

    return "/images/logos/#{file}"
  end
  def ajaxUpdate
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @image = @album.images.find(params[:albumcover])
    if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

end
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    #before_filter :split_hash, :only => [ :create, :update ]
    def index
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @images = @album.images.all
    end
    def new
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new
    end
    def create
        params[:image][:source].each do |image|
            @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
            @params = {}
            @params['source'] = image
            @image = @album.images.create(@params)
       end
        if @image.save
            if params[:image][:source].size > 1
                flash[:notice] = "Successfully added images!"
            else
                flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            end
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render "new"
            flash[:notice] = "Did not successfully add image :("
        end
    end
    def show
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def edit
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        @albumid = @album.id
        @id = @image.id
        FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/image/picture/#{@albumid}/#{@id}", :force => true)
        redirect_to admin_album_images_path(@album)
    end
    def ajaxUpdate
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:albumcover])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end
  #     def split_hash
  #         @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        # @image = @album.images
  #     array_of_pictures = params[:image][:picture]
  #     array_of_pictures.each do |pic|
  #         size = array_of_pictures.size.to_i
  #         size.times {@image.build(params[:image], :picture => pic)}
  #         @image.save
        # end
  #     end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :album_id
    has_many :images,  :dependent => :destroy
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true
end
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :source, :album_id, :albumcover, :image, :image_id
    belongs_to :album
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :album
    mount_uploader :source, PictureUploader
end
```

**View**

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin/images' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "admin.js" %>
<% end %>
<% content_for :menu do %>
    <li class="menu_item"><%=link_to "New Album", :controller => "albums", :action => "new" %></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><%= link_to "Add Images", {:controller => "images", :action => "new"}, :class => "highlight_menu"%> </li>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "< Back", admin_albums_path, :id => "return_link" %> </br>
<h1 class="section-title"> <strong style="font-weight: 600;"><%=best_in_place [:admin,@album], :title, :ok_button => :confirm %></strong></h1>
<h4 class="album-desc"><%= best_in_place [:admin,@album], :description, :type => :textarea, :ok_button => :confirm%></h4>

<%= form_tag admin_album_images_path(@album) do  %>
<% if !@images.blank? %>
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image-box">
                <div class="source">
                    <%= image_tag image.source %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="item-links">
                    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_admin_album_image_path(@album, image.id), :id => "edit"%>
                    <%= link_to "Delete", 
                        admin_album_image_path(@album, image.id),
                        :class => "item-link delete-image",
                        :method => :delete, 
                        :remote => true,
                        :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <p class="alert">No images in this album</p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Answer!**

*albums_controller*

```
def albumCoverSet
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @image = @album.images.find(params[:albumcover])
    if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

* album view *

```
<div class="image"> 
        <%= image_tag album.images.find(album.albumcover_id).source, :class => "image" %>
    </div>
```

*model*

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :album_id, :albumcover_id
    has_many :images,  :dependent => :destroy
    has_one :albumcover, :class_name => "Image"
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why radio buttons wouldn't work?  You should be able to give an id to each image on the client side.  Then selecting a radio button would ajax a message saying that the image with that id should be the cover.  You could also do this with a click (or even a popup menu) on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a 'primary_image_id' to the Album in a migration.

```
has_one :primary_image, :class_name => 'Image'
```

In your form, you can show all album.images and select one.  Radio buttons should work just fine.

Submitting the value of the param would set the primary_image_id.

Comment: I'll check it out and update you if I get it working! Thanks!

Comment: I tend to use this approach - to 'cache' values (or denormalize the database) by keeping a value on the record - especially if you are showing the record in a list.  The other approach of putting a 'primary' boolean on the image is messier to keep up to date.  Good luck!

Comment: One thing to be aware of:


Setting up a `has_one` relationship will disassociate a previously set primary image if you try to change it.

Ive found that doing the following works better in this scenario:
`belongs_to :primary_image, :class_name => 'Image', optional: true`